# Vote and favorite count "-1 down vote favorite" shown in question preview under Newest questions tab

Tags: support

In the first image, I've noticed the  first time  text like "-1 down vote favorite" written before the beginning of the question's body. It's not shown in the snippet of other questions listed in newest questions tab.

[image]

Actual question doesn't show that text.

[image]

Surprisingly, Google also show the same text,

[image]

Was that a glitch or intended behavior by the system?

Comment: This happens when people are sloppy in their copying - this particular question was copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230649/library-to-exec-application-with-timeout-python-even-in-the-case-of-task-unint.

Comment: @Undo That makes sense. I suppose by the time I opened that question separately OP already edited and removed that text from the beginning. Because it happened in the first 5 minutes frame, there was no second revision created. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“up vote *score* down vote favorite” appears at the beginning of a questions when the asker carelessly copied a question from Stack Exchange. To reiterate, this appears because it was put there by the asker.

The asker must have realized that within 5 minutes of posting (note that you saw the question when it was less than 5 minutes old). Edits made within 5 minutes of the initial posting are not tracked separately, the edit overwrites the stored initial revision; this is intended as a [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info) to fix obvious problems without leaving a permanent record. You also get a grace period after an edit that was recorded. The grace period is reset by some activities such as an edit by another user, or an answer or a comment being posted.

Google indexes the site very quickly, and doesn't necessarily notice grace period edits since they don't update any timestamp, so it may keep the pre-grace-period version in its cache for a while.

Comment: That careless copying happens when the user tries to copy the text from bottom to beginning.